# Magento - show simple products on listing page

Tags: magento, product

I'm using rwd theme of Magento, but this theme shows the configurable products on listing page. I have different colours (red, blue, yellow) in the same configurable product, and I want to show 3 simple products on listing page instead of configurable.

Is that possible? How can I do it? I'm looking for the solution but I didn't find it.

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: This is not possible. The simple products used to create configurable products are not visible on frontend individually

Comment: It is a programming question,thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change Visibility of simple product to "Catalog, Search", It will showing in product list page.

PS: you may need to disable Configurable products.

Comment: I did that before, but the frontend just show configurable products. Something that I can do in list.phtml? or where?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the "Simple configurable" product plugin?

This might help you to achieve something along this line...

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

The other way is to do it with code using a custom template / backend php override...

htp